# Is there a way to connect generic USB game controllers to a PSP 3000?

Tags: psp

There seems to be a way to connect a controller to the PSP through its USB port, like shown in the picture below of a "DOSO PSW-303".

Is there a way to do something similar that works with any generic USB controller?

[image]

Comment: That device seems to use customized PSP firmware and customized hardware, so probably not unless you create your own customized firmware and hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my findings, connecting a generic USB controller to a PSP through its USB port requires a master intermediary device, since the PSP can only function as a slave USB device, as shown below:

[image: (Block diagram: (original slave device) -> (intermediary master device) -> (generic USB game controller)]

The intermediary device in question can either be a USB-compatible microcontroller ([link #1](http://www.acidmods.com/forum/index.php/topic,22226.60.html), 2008, "gr8npwrfl"), or a PC ([link #2](http://psx-scene.com/forums/f118/ps3-controller-psp-100100/), 2010, "ThirdSeason").

The PSP also must be loaded with custom firmware for such an idea to work.